# How to set token in headers axios

Tags: axios

I am making post request with axios and these are my codes.

```
//Helper function
export const postDataApi = async (url, post, token) => {
  const res = await axios.post(`/api/${url}`, post, {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer: ${token}` },
  });

  return res;
};
```

---

```
 // Sending request
 const res = await api.postDataApi("auth/register", data, token);
 console.log(res);
```

After sending the request, I take my access token in server side but in the `res.data`.

[image]

But when we look at `config.headers` we see that token is undefined

[image]

It is because my helper function postDataApi can't see the token parameter since it makes its functionality before the sending request.

When using Postman, I could easily set the token manually but I don't know how to do it in React.js by using axios.

When I researched I found that I should use `axios.defaults.headers.post`but becuase I am beginner I couldn't handle it

How can I set my token in config/headers ?

This is the server side

```
 return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      accessToken,
      newUser,
 });
```

Comment: // Sending request
 const res = await api.postDataApi("auth/register", data);
 console.log(res);

in your code, you didn't pass the token I guess because of this.

Comment: you are not passing the token as a parameter to the postDataApi

Comment: Actually this is what I can't do. Because it passes as undefined when I do it.

Comment: why cant't you pass the token inside the function? any reason?

Comment: Because my token is not going to headers. And when I set it as req.headers, it doesn't show in the config this time either. In the edit, I showed what was returned from the server. So I can't catch my token in front end.

Comment: are you using axios in server side or client side?

Comment: Just using in client side

Comment: if you are using it on client side like react , you can pass in the token as 3rd param

Comment: you can pass the token from a component where you are using the helper method, you can do that, there is no problem in that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236897/discussion-between-cihan-ozcan-and-sachin-ananthakumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned that you are not passing the token correctly while making the API call.

So, instead of passing token to every API call, you can think of it storing somewhere locally like in the Local Storage or in Cookies, and try to access it in the following manner:

```
export const postDataApi = async (url, post) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
              "Authorization": `Bearer ${Cookies.get("jwt")}`,
        },
    };
    const res = await axios.post(`/api/${url}`, post, config);
}
```

Another way to do this properly is to use [Axios Interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)

Answer (score 0):

```
const res = await api.postDataApi("auth/register", data, token); // Pass the token
 console.log(res);
```

if you want to set the headers for every request you can use this

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'token';
```